# How to update query in apollo client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

Let's say I have a simple data model like this

```
User
 - email
 - password
 - Profile
    - profile_image
    - address
    - phone_number
```

When I visit the user's profile page, I use useQuery and query user from server

```
const ME = gql`
  query {
    me {
      email
      profile {
        profileImage
        address
        phoneNumber
      }
  }
`; 
const {loading, data, refetch} = useQuery(ME);
```

And when I want to update a profile. I will do this

```
const UPDATE_PROFILE = gql`
  mutation($profileImage: String!, $address: String!, $phoneNumber: String!) {
    updateProfile(profileImage: $profileImage, address: $address, phoneNumber: $phoneNumber) {
      profileImage
      address
      phoneNumber
    }
  }
`;

const [updateProfile, {loading}] = useMutation(UPDATE_PROFILE, {
  onCompleted(data) {
    // Refetch to refresh whole user data
    refetch();
  }
}
```

I just want to display new updated user info in the page, So What I do is calling `refetch()` from useQuery(ME).

But I found that I can use refetchQueries() from this [doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#recipes).
Which will be a better choice? What is the difference between them?

Comment: imagine mutation in other part of app, from other component

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `refetchQueries` and `refetch`:

- `refetchQueries`: you can refetch any queries after a mutation including your `ME` query or other queries like `getMessageList`, `getListUser`,...

  > `refetchQueries` is the simplest way of updating the cache. With `refetchQueries` you can specify one or more queries that you want to run after a mutation is completed in order to refetch the parts of the store that may have been affected by the mutation ([refetchQueries doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#recipes)).
- `refetch`: you just can refetch query `ME` when your use `refetch` which is one of the results of `useQuery(ME)`.

  > A function that allows you to refetch the query and optionally pass in new variables ([refetch doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#usequery)).

In your case, if you want to refetch your `ME` data, you can use `refetch`. On the other hand, if your want to update other queries you should use `refetchQueries`.
In my experience, I prefer using `refetchQueries` after a mutation to using `refetch`.